# Unable to run a simple python program

Tags: python

I started learning python. Here is a simple program:

```
class StudentRepo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.student_list = []

    def add(self, student):
        self.student_list.append(student)

    def get_list(self):
        self.student_list




class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.age = age
        self.name = name




from models.student.Student import Student
from services.student.StudentRepo import StudentRepo

s1 = Student("A", 10)
s2 = Student("B", 11)

# What is the issue here ?
StudentRepo.add(s1)
StudentRepo.add(s2)

studentList = StudentRepo.get_list()
for student in studentList:
    print(student.name)
```

What is the issue with `s1 = Student("A", 10)` ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the exception you are receiving because you describe the issue is with `s1 = Student("A", 10)` but it looks like the issue you are having is because you haven't created an instance of `StudentRepo` you are calling directly on the class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python class static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735392/python-class-static-methods)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I'm not sure the OP is looking for a `staticmethod` because they are manipulating an instance variable created in `__init__()`.

Comment: For more advice on how to write a good question, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code. First, this:

```
def get_list(self):
    self.student_list
```

should be:

```
def get_list(self):
    return self.student_list
```

Second, you're using the class `StudentRepo` where you should be using an instance of `StudentRepo`:

```
s1 = Student("A", 10)
s2 = Student("B", 11)

my_roster = StudentRepo()

my_roster.add(s1)
my_roster.add(s2)

studentList = my_roster.get_list()
for student in studentList:
    print(student.name)
```